# Sum of Gamma functions (product pairs)

Tags: summation, gamma-function

This is my first time asking a question on stackexchange. Is there an analytical expression for the following summation of Gamma functions?

$\sum_{t=0}^m \Gamma (A + t) \Gamma (B + m -t) = ?$

for any $A > 0$ and $B >0$.

Thanks!